# If $I \subseteq \sqrt{J}$, then there is an $n \in \mathbb{N}$ such that $I^n \subseteq J$

Tags: abstract-algebra, commutative-algebra, ideals

I am stuck at the following exercise:

> Let $R$ be a commutative ring with unity and let $I,J$ be ideals in $R$. Show that if $I \subseteq \sqrt{J}$ and $I$ is finitely generated, then there is an $n \in \mathbb{N}$ such that $I^n \subseteq J$.

I know that since $I$ is finitely generated there are $a_1, \ldots, a_k \in I$ such that $$I = Ra_1+\ldots +Ra_k.$$

If I am not mistaken $I^n = \bigg\{ \sum_{i=1}^m b_1\cdot\ldots\cdot b_n \quad \bigg\vert \quad m \in \mathbb{N} \text{ and } b_j \in I \bigg\}$. But I do not see how I should argue from here that $I^n \subseteq J$. Could you please help me?

Comment: Hint: there is a $n_0$ such that every $n_0$-th power of any the generators is in $J$. Thus, there is a $n_1 > 0$ such that every monomial of degree $\geq n_1$ in the generators is in $J$. Show that $I^{n_1} \subset J$.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. Just to clearify: With "monomial of degree $\ge n_1$ in the generators" you mean $rX^{n_1}$ for some $r \in R$, where we can plug in one of the $a_i$ for $X$, right?

Comment: For instance if $I = (a, b)$ and you know that $a^2 \in J$ and $b^2 \in J$, that isn't enough to conclude that $I^2 = (a^2, ab, b^2) \subseteq J$ because you don't know about $ab$. But, you can say that $I^3 = (a^3, a^2b, ab^2, b^3) \subseteq J$ since each of those generators is in $J$.

Comment: No, I meant $a_1^{m_1}a_2^{m_2} \ldots a_k^{m_k}$ with the sum of the $m_i$ exceeding $n_1$.

Comment: Thanks a lot to both of you for your help, I got it now.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

From the comments:

If $I = (a_1,\dots,a_m)$ then $I^n = (a_1^{i_1}\dots a_m^{i_m} : i_1 + \dots + i_m = n)$.

There is some $n_0$ such that $a_i^{n_0} \in J$ for $i \in \{1,\dots,m\}$. Hence, you need to argue that for large enough $n \ge n_0$, each of the monomials $a_1^{i_1}\dots a_m^{i_m}$ will be divisible by some $a_i^{n_0}$.

E.g. if $I = (a, b)$ then $I^2 = (a^2, ab, b^2)$ and $I^3 = (a^3, a^2b, ab^2, b^3)$ and $I^4 = (a^4, a^3b, a^2b^2, ab^3, b^4)$, etc. So the generators of $I^3$ are each divisible by $a^2$ or $b^2$, the generators of $I^5$ are divisible by either $a^3$ or $b^3$.